# How can I use webpack "output.devtoolNamespace" in angular

Tags: webpack, angular-webpack

I have an angular application.

In the browser I see the source root as
webpack://src...

I want to use other namespaces like
webpack://web-component-a/...
webpack://web-component-b/...

in webpack documentation I have read I can do this with:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputdevtoolnamespace

But in angular 9 I dont have a webpack config. How can I merge a custom webpack partial file and customize the "output" object without redefining it

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out:

```
ng add ngx-build-plus
```

webpack.partial.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    output: {
        devtoolNamespace: 'client-a'
    },
    devtool: 'eval' // hint: namespace works not standalone
}
```

run with partial webpack config:

```
ng serve --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js --port 7201 --single-bundle
```

expected result:

[image]